# Удаление большого числа строк из таблицы Transact-SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql

В общем нужно удалить из таблицы Nodes порядка 110000 записей, только их id указывается не явно а берётся из другой таблицы.

```
DELETE FROM Nodes
WHERE  (id NOT IN
           (SELECT DISTINCT node_id
                   FROM Relations))
```

В `SELECT DISTINCT id FROM @gh` гдето около 20000 записей и в результате удаления не совершаются изза истекшего таймаута.

**Update**:
Если удалять по пакетам и убрать DISTINCT то возникает другая ошибка связанная с нехваткой памяти и завершением процесса SQL Server

```
WHILE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Nodes WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT node_id FROM Relations))
    DELETE TOP (100) Nodes WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT node_id FROM Relations)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На самом деле проблема решена сторонним способом через ADO.NET. Сначала загрузил в список всех id из таблицы Nodes. Затем в другой список загрузил node_id из таблицы Relations. И наконец циклом пробежался по первому списку выполняя запрос на удаление тех строк id которых не содержится во втором списке. Это полностью решает проблему с накоплением памяти.

```
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(MainWindow._connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        var readerRelations =
            new SqlCommand("SELECT DISTINCT node_id FROM Relations", connection).ExecuteReader();
        var DistinctRelations = new List<int>();
        while (readerRelations.Read())
        {
            DistinctRelations.Add((int)readerRelations.GetValue(0));
        }
        readerRelations.Close();

        var readerNodes = new SqlCommand("SELECT id FROM Nodes", connection).ExecuteReader();
        var AllNodes = new List<int>();
        while (readerNodes.Read())
        {
            AllNodes.Add((int)readerNodes.GetValue(0));
        }
        readerNodes.Close();
        int iterator = 0;
        int NodesCount = AllNodes.Count;
        int lastpercent = 0;
        foreach (var node in AllNodes)
        {
            int percent = (int)(iterator * 1.0 / NodesCount * 100);
            if (percent == lastpercent + 1)
            {
                lastpercent = percent;
                DeleteUnnecesseryNodesChanged(this,
                                                new MyEventArgs("Удаление ненужных точек", (int)percent));
            }
            if (!DistinctRelations.Contains(node))
            {
                try
                {
                    new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM Nodes WHERE id = " + node, connection).ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    var t = e.ToString();
                    throw new Exception(t);
                }
            }
            iterator++;
        }

        connection.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Если node_id - уникальный, создайте ключ на id.
2. Уберите DISTINCT.
3. Попробуйте использовать внешнее соединение вместо NOT IN.
4. Разбивать на порции по диапазонам id.

Comment: плохо разобрались: node_id не уникальный потому и DISTINCT. А вот по поводу последних 2х пунктов можно подробнее?

Comment: Distinct все равно не нужен. Он вызывает лишнюю сортировку.
3. DELETE FROM Nodes
from nodes left join Relations on id=node_id
WHERE  id is null
4. Удалять в цикле, разбивая id на диапазоны.

Comment: Пожалуйста посмотрите я обновил шапку.

Comment: Делайте пакеты по node_id.

Answer (score 2):

```
DELETE FROM Nodes
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Relations r WHERE r.node_id = id)
```

И создать индекс на Relations.node_id.

Comment: на node_id есть индекс. Пожалуйста посмотрите я обновил шапку.

Comment: Можно еще попробовать TOP 1 в подзапрос добавить.

Answer (score 2):

1. Есть запросы, которые будут выполняться долго несмотря на любые ухищрения. Насколько я понимаю, это свойство соединения со стороны клиента, а не со стороны сервера. В MS Managament Studio это устанваливается в Сервис->Параметры->Выполнение запроса-> Вермя ожидания запроса.
2. Попробуйте такой синтакис

   `DELETE FROM 
       Nodes 
   FROM    Nodes N 
       JOIN Relations R ON R.node_id=N.id`